# Exclude items from subreport based on main report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I need your assistant in getting the appropriate way to exclude some of the items from the subreport based on the items that are passed from the main report and to show the extra items which are in the subreport. What I mean is that I am having a main report that is displaying the deal numbers and some descriptions which belongs to each deal. Also, the subreport is having the same fields which are the deal numbers and some descriptions.I want the subreport to exclude the deal numbers which are displayed in the main report and and to show the extra deal numbers which are in the subreport.

My report structure is:

```
Group Header #1: Security Group Name (Bond/Treasury)

Group Header #2: Security Code Reference (XXY/AAAA/BBB)

Group Header #3: Deal No

Detail: Deal No, Amount, Effective Date

Group Footer #1:

Group Footer #2:

Group Footer #3:
```

The subreport is having the same structure and I placed it in the Group Header #2.

An example is that:

Main report:

```
GH1: Bonds
GH2: A.B123
GH3: 123
Detail: 123 1000 12-FEB-2000
```

Sub report:

```
GH1: Bonds
GH2: A.B123
GH3: 123
Detail: 123 1000 12-FEB-2000
        111 2000 11-JAN-1999
```

The result should be

```
GH1: Bonds
GH2: A.B123
GH3: 123
Detail: 123 1000 12-FEB-2000
        111 2000 11-JAN-1999
```

I added a subreport link which is a parameter for the deal no from the main report to be passed to the subreport. And in the subreport I defined {Command.deal_no} <> {?PM-Deal_no}in the select expert. However, the extra deals are not coming.

Can you please assist me in this issue

Comment: I don't understand your example.  The result is the same as the sub-report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`You approach is correct but you need to edit a bit on the sub report part.`

Instead of adding the condition in `subreport select expert`. write the same condition in `supress formula` for `Detail section` of `subreport`.

By this all the records that matches with the value from sub report will supressed and rest will be displayed.